# Event listener's response type

Tags: php, symfony

I have a very simple controller returning JSON response:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request) : JsonResponse
    {
        return new JsonResponse(array('aaa'));
    }

}
```

Chrome console shows `type/json` in header, which is correct. I want to set up event listener converting these json responses to html and adding some html markup, so I created `AppBundle\Event\Listener' namespace:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Event\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class ConvertToHtmlResponse
{

    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event -> isMasterRequest())
        {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event -> getRequest();

        // Only send back HTML if the requestor allows it
        if (!$request -> headers -> has('Accept') || (false === strpos($request -> headers -> get('Accept'), 'text/html')))
        {
            return;
        }

        $response = $event -> getResponse();
        switch ($request -> getRequestFormat()) {
            case 'json':
                $prettyprint_lang = 'js';
                $content = json_encode(json_decode($response -> getContent()), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                break;

            case 'xml':
                $prettyprint_lang = 'xml';
                $content = $response -> getContent();
                break;

            default:
                return;
        }

        $response -> setContent(
                '<html><body>' .
                '<pre class="prettyprint lang-' . $prettyprint_lang . '">' .
                htmlspecialchars($content) .
                '</pre>' .
                '<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>' .
                '</body></html>'
        );

        // Set the request type to HTML
        $response -> headers -> set('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        $request -> setRequestFormat('html');

        // Overwrite the original response
        $event -> setResponse($response);
    }

}
```

And added it to `services.yml`:

```
services:
    listener.kernel.convert_html:
        class: AppBundle\Event\Listener\ConvertToHtmlResponse
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response }
```

---

And the problem is that `$event -> getResponse()` in the event listener returns 'html', and the response header inside the listener is also html, the controller and method are correct. Only chrome console shows the right headers.

What's wrong?